# Wireless Network Is not Working

Tags: elementary-website

[image: Disabled wireless]

I have both LAN and wireless network devices. The problem is, when I am trying to connect to a network it doesn't shows anything, Only giving a message that wifi disabled. But in settings, the wireless option is already enabled. How can I solve this problem?